# Generating self-signed SSL certificate for apache on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, apache-http-server, ssl-certificate

I do not have any idea how to generate self-signed SSL certificate for Apache on Windows Vista, but I have to do that.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install [OpenSSL for Windows](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), which is free.

After installation, open command line (`cmd.exe`), go to installation directory and run appropriate `openssl` commands.

```
openssl.exe req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt -days 1000 -nodes
```

This generates `server.key` (private key for your Apache) and `server.crt` (self-signed certificate). Remember to protect your private key.

For installation to Apache2 (in Linux):

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl
```

Change correct paths to following lines (paths to your new key and certificate):

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Save and run `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` (or if your distribution uses some different way, not that command).

Comment: hi, thank for reply. I have already install apache with open SSL, so is there any need to separately install openSSL on vista. I have configure my site with apache and its working fine with http. But I have to do the same for https. please reply me.

Comment: @Lokesh: No, you don't need to install OpenSSL separately.  The `openssl.exe` tool (and required libraries) should be included with an SSL-enabled Apache distribution.  Just go into Apache's `conf\extra` folder and edit the `httpd-ssl.conf` file, then make sure it's being `Include`'d from your main `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Hi... I am using Xampp on windows 10 and I got my certificate and key... By following another site this is my virtural host at **httpd-vhosts.conf**: `<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\talin\Documents\Code\Web\Bugs!"
ServerName alphatest.cf
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:\xampp\apache\cert\server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\xampp\apache\cert\server.key"
</VirtualHost> 
`

Comment: My apache server doesn't start and i could find any errors in the log...

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that you need this certificate for local development. If so, there is a very useful tool for this called *mkcert*. It generates the certificates and can add them to your local certificates, so that it becomes trusted. I found it extremely easy to use since I can achieve all of that by just typing two commands in the shell.

In this page there are instructions on how to install it:
https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert

If you have choco, you can install it with

```
choco install mkcert
```

Once installed, you need to install it's local authority certificate, so that it could be trusted.

```
mkcert -install
```

This will prompt a window asking for confirmation.

After that, you can proceed with certificate generation. The command is very simple and requires just the domains that you want this certificate to be trusted in. In my case, I want it for development in localhost, so I will type:

```
mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

It creates two .pem file, which you'll need for Apache.

Copy the two files to the machine hosting your website. The typical directory for ssl certificates on linux is /etc/ssl/certs/

As Olli mentioned, you can run the following on linux to enable the ssl:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
```

Change the following lines in your default-ssl.conf file to the names of the certificates. The file is typically located in one of these:

- /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
- /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/

There should be a VirtualHost directive, having the following lines:

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Change the paths in these lines. The first line must point to the file without the "-key.pem" suffix, the second one has it. Don't worry about the extension differences bertween .crt/.key/.pem, mkcert outputs you two ".pem" files that are just fine.

Now, you need to restart the server to make it pick the certificates. To do so, you can type one of the following. It changes from distribution to distribution:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart httpd2
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why revive this old, specific question now? It's not even clear the question refers to running  Apache on Linux and info on Apache config/restart is needed? These are separate topics. I'd consider this a good answer if it stopped after *It creates two .pem file, which you'll need for Apache.*.

Comment: Sadly it's the first answer that pops in Google and the other results are irrelevant. I've spent many hours making ssl work correctly and I want to contribute by posting the best solution I found. Other people won't need to waste as much time as I did.

Comment: Hah, forgot about that reason! Now I am curious about the search term :-D Still you're a bit over-answering the question with the Apache stuff IMO. You could find fitting questions, post an answer there and link them from here.